# What is changing the page orientation for Mobile version on my first Web Page

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, web

I don't know which function is changing the default aspect for the Mobile devices.
(Good) This is how it looks on Desktop: ![Screenshot] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxGDE.jpg)
(Bad) This is on Mobile: ![Screenshot] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVsBe.jpg)

Is it in this .js file? https://gist.github.com/paulzamfira/1c87a6a0fe44e6ab809f74cb597de57b
Or main.css  : https://gist.github.com/paulzamfira/73a93cb5f938d0201f75da4734e18d41

I want it to remain landscape like the Desktop version.
Thank you for the help! Really appreciate it!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow. Would you please post your actual code here rather than links? You'll get much better feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both files manipulate with `max-width` and `orientation` CSS params. in main.css file you can find e.g. `@media screen and (max-width: 736px)` or `@media screen and (orientation: portrait)` - styles for some dimensions (screens not larger that 736px), and one of these kind-of-ifs are making this vertical layout conversion